# Date compare script works in every browser except Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var myDate = new Date()
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() - 1);
$(".container").children("div").each(function(){
var thisdate=$(this).attr("data-date");
var dateOfGame = new Date(thisdate); 
if(thisdate!="" && dateOfGame <= myDate){
$(this).remove();}});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div data-date="8/2/17"></div>
 <div data-date="8/29/17"></div>
 </div>
```

The script removes outdated elements from my page a day after the event. However, on Edge it acts as though every element is outdated and removes them all from the DOM.

Comment: This is year start issue with Edge. check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inspected your code and the issue is, when you are using chrome, *8/29/17* is interpreted as *8/29/2017* and in Edge, it is interpreted as **8/29/1917**

#### To verify this

run the below code and check console in edge and chrome.

```js
 var myDate = new Date()
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() - 1);
$(".container").children("div").each(function(){
var thisdate=$(this).attr("data-date");
var dateOfGame = new Date(thisdate); 
console.log(myDate, dateOfGame);
if(thisdate!="" && dateOfGame <= myDate){
$(this).remove();}});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div data-date="8/2/17"></div>
 <div data-date="8/29/17"></div>
 </div>
```

#### To fix this

You have to use *2017* in order to make edge support this

```js
var myDate = new Date()
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() - 1);
$(".container").children("div").each(function(){
var thisdate=$(this).attr("data-date");
var dateOfGame = new Date(thisdate); 
console.log(dateOfGame <= myDate , myDate, dateOfGame);
if(thisdate!="" && dateOfGame <= myDate){
$(this).remove();}});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div data-date="8/2/2017"></div>
 <div data-date="8/29/2017"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: can't believe i didn't think to try this. cheers, you're brilliant